spyder can't write files to document folder in onedrive
I can't use spyder to pro-grammatically write any files (.xlsx, .csv, .pkl) to document folder in onedrive. I didn't have any of those files opened or under syncing.
I input
test.to_excel('test.xlsx')
and I get error message as
FileCreateError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

However, spyder can read files from the folder without a problem.
When I try to save any files manually to Onedrive, it also work find.
When I create another folder called document2, spyder can also both read and write.
Any suggestion of what might be happening here.
Thank you so much
May
